# Symfony 3 error: Variable "repository" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig, runtime

I've been stuck on this for days! I'm able to save form data to a database, but I'm not able to retrieve that data in order to display it. I always get the  500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime (Variable "repository" does not exist). Here's my controller:

```
class FormController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a message instance
        $message = new Message();

        //assign some placeholder data
        $message->setName('Billy');
        $message->setAddy('ok@hotmail.com');
        $message->setSubject('Notice');
        $message->setBody('Practice Delayed');

        //method creates and renders form
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($message)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('addy', TextType::class)
            ->add('subject', TextType::class)
            ->add('body', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-lg')))
            ->getForm();

        //method checks if the form is submitted
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //if form is submitted and data is valid...
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //fetch data
            $name = $form->get('name')->getData();
            $addy = $form->get('addy')->getData();
            $subject = $form->get('subject')->getData();
            $body = $form->get('body')->getData();

            //set data
            $message->setName($name);
            $message->setAddy($addy);
            $message->setSubject($subject);
            $message->setBody($body);

            //entity manager
            $em =  $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Message')->findAll();
            $em->persist($message);
            $em->flush();

            if (!$repository) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No messages'
                );
            }
            return $this->render('default/output.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Here's my index.html.twig file, which works great and lets me save data to the database:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
            {% block form_row %}
            {% spaceless %}
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="container">
                        <div class="form_row">
                            {{ form(form) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endspaceless %}
        {% endblock form_row %}
{% endblock %}
```

But here's my output.html.twig file, which gives me the error when I click "Send":

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Genus</th>
                <th># of species</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for key in repository %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ key.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ key.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ key.addy }}</td>
                        <td>{{ key.subject }}</td>
                        <td>{{ key.body }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the repository variable to your Twig template.
For example :

```
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array('form' =>  $form->createView(), 'repository' => $repository));
```

Comment: omg that worked perfectly! You saved my butt and made my day! Thank You!